# Using ArrayList.ToArray(Parameter?) in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I don't understand how to use

```
    Dim List As New ArrayList
    Dim Strings() As String

    List.Add("hello")

    'The following line should simply return an array of strings:
    Strings = List.ToArray(Of String)    '(syntax error)
```

Could only find C# examples and didn't figured it out.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The example is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.toarray?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_ArrayList_ToArray_System_Type_). `Dim myArr As String() = CType(myAL.ToArray(GetType(String)), String())`.

Comment: It works, thank you.

Comment: You should use a strongly typed [**`List(Of T)`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) instead of an `ArrayList`. The latter is pretty much obsolete these days and, as you have noticed, is not bound to a specific type.

Comment: Thank you for that hint.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you should be using a `List(Of String)` in the firtst place if at all possible.  It's then simply:

```
myList.ToArray()
```

to get a `String` array.  If you're stuck with the `ArrayList` though, the correct option is:

```
myList.Cast(Of String)().ToArray()
```

The `Cast` method takes in an `IEnumerable` and outputs an `IEnumerable(Of T)`.  The latter is what's required by most extension methods commonly called from the `Enumerable` class, of which `ToArray` is an example.